In the Fischer Esterification mechanism, what happens to the second alcohol group used catalytically for proton removal?
In the Fischer Esterification Mechanism, the alcohol group is used twice catalytically as I have shown with $A_1$ in the picture. While the first $A_1$ gets converted back to $A_1$, I'm not sure how the second $A_1$ molecule used for the proton removal at the final step to form the Ester gets converted back to $A_1$ from $A_2$.
Could anybody explain?


What second ethanol? A proton is the catalyst. The stoichiometry is one-to-one although excess alcohol is used to shift the equilibrium to the right. This mechanism has been discussed proviously on ChemSE. Look here or enter - Fischer Esterification - in the Search window at the top of the page.

You have correctly drawn steps for the initial protonation and alcohol addition in the Fischer esterification mechanism to give the tetrahedral intermediate $\bf{I}$ (see steps 1 and 2 in my scheme below, which is a modified version of that given here:

You incorrectly chose an alcohol to do the proton transfer in the next step. The better choice would be the bisulfate ion available due to the initial protonation. Although we show use of conjugate base to do this work as a matter of fact, this proton exchange is also automatic amongst all three oxygen atoms (basicity of which are very compatible) in the tetrahedral intermediate $\bf{I}$ (compare intra vs inter hydrogen transfer). Once one of the $\ce{OH}$ groups in the tetrahedral intermediate $\bf{II}$ is protonated it becomes a good leaving group, water (see tetrahedral intermediate $\bf{III}$), and leaves with concomitant donation of a lone pair by the other $\ce{OH}$ group (or as you have done in your scheme, by a $\ce{OR}$ group; but we consider the most possible process, which would give the product because all of these processes are in equilibrium) to give the intermediate $\bf{IV}$. It will be deprotonated by the conjugate base of the acid catalyst yielding the final ester product and also the catalytic acid (that's why the reaction is called "acid catalyzed").

I strongly suggest reconsidering which species are the most acidic and basic in your reaction environment. If you maintain that $\ce{R-OH}$ is the base that deprotonates your organic substrate, then in the first step, $\ce{H2SO4}$ would not protonate the carbonyl oxygen ($\ce{-C=O}$). Instead, your proposed base, $\ce{R-OH}$, would predominantly exist in its protonated form, $\ce{R-OH2+}$, due to the reaction with $\ce{H2SO4}$. This protonated species would then act as the catalyst.
If you incorporate this simple consideration in the first step, you will also see that the catalyst would be recovered in the last step of the mechanism as $\ce{R-OH2+}$.
